# Implication problems(cant seem to find the mistake)

Tags: logic

So our professor gave us a problem: We had to prove that $q\vee[(q→r)\wedge(q\wedge¬r)\wedge(r→p)]$ is a tautology by elemination process. I did it but instead what I got is that its equivalent to $q$ (i also tried the truth table). Can someone confirm whether I messed up or it actually is equivalent to $q$?

Comment: It's indeed not a tautology .. but it is not equivalent to $p$ either ... Can you show what you did? ... and what do you mean by 'prove by elimination process'?

Comment: Im sorry, i meant q.uh,i guess in english the right word is simplyfying(?).i mean by using the already known identites such as p and (p or q)=p.(forgive my poor math vocabulary)

Comment: It's equivalent to $q$. (@Rohan probably misread the clause $(q\land\neg r)$ as $(q\lor\neg r)$, which would make the formula equivalent to $q\lor\neg r$.)